# How to get a node on SOAP UI's test case XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy, soapui, assertions

I had been stuck while playing with the SOAP UI getting started tutorial because I can't produce an assertion condition for a simple test.
I'm Using the XPATH method to test the following SOAP message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCitiesByCountryResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
            <GetCitiesByCountryResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
      <Table>
        <Country>Belarus</Country>
        <City>Riga Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Mauritius</Country>
        <City>Plaisance Mauritius</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Mauritius</Country>
        <City>Rodrigues</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Cyprus</Country>
        <City>Ercan</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Cyprus</Country>
        <City>Larnaca Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Cyprus</Country>
        <City>Athalassa</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Cyprus</Country>
        <City>Paphos Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Cyprus</Country>
        <City>Akrotiri</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Niederosterreich / Lugplatz  Vos</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Graz-Thalerhof-Flughafen</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Innsbruck-Flughafen</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Klagenfurt-Flughafen</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Linz / Hoersching-Flughafen</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Salzburg-Flughafen</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Wien / Schwechat-Flughafen</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Aigen Im Ennstal</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Horsching Aus-Afb</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Schwaz Heliport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Tulln</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Austria</Country>
        <City>Zeltweg</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Jakutsk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Cul'Man</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Ekimchan</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Habarovsk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Troickoe</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Anadyr</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Buhta Providenja</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Magadan</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Petropavlovsk-Kamchatskij</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Juzhno-Sahalinsk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Vladivostok</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Chita</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Irkutsk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Ust'Ordynskij</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Bodajbo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Kirensk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Nizhneudinsk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Horinsk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Ulan-Ude</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Arhangel'Sk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Kotlas</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>St. Peterburg</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Murmansk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Velikie Luki</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Tot'Ma</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Vologda</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Belarus</Country>
        <City>Vitebsk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Belarus</Country>
        <City>Minsk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Barnaul</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Enisejsk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Novosibirsk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Krasnodar</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Mineral'Nye Vody</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Rostov-Na-Donu</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Adler</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Elista</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Volgograd</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Hanty-Mansijsk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Surgut</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Ekaterinburg</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Brjansk</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Moscow / Sheremet'Ye</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Tver</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Voronez</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Moscow / Vnukovo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Ust', Kulom</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Syktyvkar</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Penza</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Russian Federation</Country>
        <City>Samara</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Brunei Darussalam</Country>
        <City>Brunei Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Archerfield Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Amberley Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Alice Springs Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Brisbane Airport M. O</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Coolangatta Airport Aws</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Cairns Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Charleville Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Gladstone</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Longreach Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Mount Isa Amo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Mackay Mo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Oakey Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Proserpine Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Rockhampton Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Broome Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Townsville Amo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Weipa City</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Gove Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Tennant Creek Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Yulara Aws</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Albury Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Devonport East</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Goldstream Aws</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>East Sale Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Hobart Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Launceston Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Laverton Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Moorabbin Airport Aws</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Mount Gambier Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Mildura Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Melbourne Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Macquarie Island</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Wynyard West</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Adelaide Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Albany Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Broken Hill Patton Street</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Ceduna Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Derby</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Darwin Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Bullsbrook Pearce Amo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Edinburgh M. O.</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Forrest Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Geraldton Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Kalgoorlie Boulder Amo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Kununurra Kununurra Aws</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Leigh Creek Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Learmonth Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Meekatharra Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Port Hedland Pardoo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Parafield Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Belmont Perth Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Katherine Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Woomera Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Bankstown Airport Aws</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Canberra</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Coffs Harbour Mo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Cooma</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Camden Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Dubbo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Norfolk Island Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Nowra Ran Air Station</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Richmond Aus-Afb</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Sydney Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Tamworth Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Wagga Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Williamtown Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
    </NewDataSet>]]></GetCitiesByCountryResult>
        </GetCitiesByCountryResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**How to find XPath to City- Rodrigues?**
**I am using this:**

//*:GetCitiesByCountryResponse/*:GetCitiesByCountryResult/*:NewDataSet/*:Table[1]/*:City[1]

**And it is giving error**
XPathContains assertion failed for path 
 Exception:Missing content for xpath [declare namespace soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace ns1='http://www.webserviceX.NET';
//*:GetCitiesByCountryResponse/*:GetCitiesByCountryResult/*:NewDataSet/*:Table[1]/*:City[1]] in Response

Comment: Since there is `cdata`, you may not be able to get it using xpath. Use groovy script instead.

Comment: @Rao Can you please help me with that?

Comment: please check the answer.

Comment: Maybe you should have tried reading the documentation beyond just getting started. https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/working-with-cdata.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it is mentioned in the comment, use `Script Assertion` instead of existing `Xpath` Assertion. Having said that, you do not have to add any additional test step for the test case with below script. Just add the script assertion for the same `SOAP Request` test step where you get the above mentioned response.
Please follow the in-line comments.

```
/**
* This is script assertion for the soap request test step.
* Extracts CDATA of response first.
* Later checks if the xpath is ok
**/
//Closure to extract data of given node name
def searchData = { data, element ->
   def parsedData = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)
   parsedData.'**'.find {it.name() == element} as String
}

//Closure to check the xpath
def searchByXpath = {data, xpath ->
   def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(data)
   def xpathResult = holder.getNodeValue(xpath)
   log.info "Xpath result : ${xpathResult}"
   xpathResult
}

//check if the response is non empty
assert context.response, "Response is empty or null"

//Gets the CDATA part of the response
def cdata = searchData(context.response, 'GetCitiesByCountryResult')

//Gets the xpath result
def cityName = 'Rodrigues'
def result = (searchByXpath(cdata, "//Table/City[. = '$cityName']/text()") == cityName) ? true : false 
log.info "Is city ${cityName} exist in the table: ${result}" 

//Check the xpath result is true(i.e., given city name exists in the table)
assert result, "${cityName} does not exist in the result table"
```

The above tests for an existing City.

In case, if you want to do a negative test i.e., **a city should not exists**, use below code snippet.

Assume,for instance, there is no City `San Francisco` in the table and want to assert.

```
/**
* Demonstration of negative assertion
* Given city should not exists
**/
def cityName1 = 'San Francisco'
def result1 = (searchByXpath(cdata, "//Table/City[. = '$cityName1']/text()") == cityName1) ? true : false
log.info "Is city ${cityName1} exist in the table: ${result1}" 

//Check the xpath result is false (i.e., given city name does not exist in the table)
assert !result1, "${cityName1} exists in the result table"
```

Comment: While Using the SanFrancisco example it is throwing an error. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9g60o2t57ouxnus/Screenshot%202016-12-06%2022.02.36.png?dl=0          Also the Rodrigues example, I changed the city Name even then it is passing always. https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7etfrxth83cpeg/Screenshot%202016-12-06%2022.05.08.png?dl=0    Please help

Comment: I have added the screenshots link in the comment. I do it here again https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7etfrxth83cpeg/Screenshot%202016-12-06%2022.05.08.png?dl=0   https://www.dropbox.com/s/9g60o2t57ouxnus/Screenshot%202016-12-06%2022.02.36.png?dl=0

Comment: Thank you for the screen shots. Note that the `Script Assertion` is **VALID** from your screen shot for the first part. i.e., the assertion is passed successfully. The second part is an extension to the first part. Use it if you need to do negative assertion as needed. In the example given above checks if there is no `San Francisco` which is also true. So, both positive and negative assertion should be passed.

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you please recheck the change? The change is in the last statement i.e., `assert` statement

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but In this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7etfrxth83cpeg/Screenshot%202016-12-06%2022.05.08.png?dl=0  you see, I have entered city name as **RODRIGUESSSS** but still it gets passed, although it should not? and here https://www.dropbox.com/s/rchl4s9bri9irop/Screenshot%202016-12-06%2023.10.31.png?dl=0 the city I entered does not exist so shouldn't it fail, as I am using negative assertion?  Sorry for sounding too naive, but I have just started learning it.

Comment: Have you noticed just previous comment requesting you to try the updated answer? Looks not from your screen shots. So, please try the changed script.

Comment: After using the edited script, it is getting failed for using the city which exists in XML  https://www.dropbox.com/s/pos7ngktns6b51g/Screenshot%202016-12-06%2023.17.19.png?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, looks I missed something. Updated the answer again. This time change is `def result` statement.

Comment: Hey, I still think there is some error, I have added wrong city but the test is getting passed https://www.dropbox.com/s/iuybbtd8zaz81q4/Screenshot%202016-12-06%2023.33.39.png?dl=0  and for the negative script that is showing error when I enter a city that is not in the XML https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0cy1e47a6hxaf3/Screenshot%202016-12-06%2023.35.02.png?dl=0

Comment: looks there is some issue with soapui.

Comment: You mean with my version, I am using 5.2.1 and is it working fine in your case?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the trouble. I realized that my tests were in sufficient. Now, updated my answer again. Please try it once, change is in `def result` statement.

Comment: Off course, Could you also share some good resources where I can study about SoapUI and get more familiar to it.